# Odd formatting bug in display of assembly code

Tags: bug

I hit an odd, though not critical bug in the display of assembly language code on the question [Disassembler for intel 8080](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200957/disassembler-for-intel-8080). There's a block of assembly code where the format is:

```
opcode operand1 operand2   comment
```

for each line. The poster originally formatted it using a block quote, but noted that it didn't look right. I changed it to be formatted as code, but saw something odd.

When I first did it, I hadn't lined up the comments. So I went back and lined them all up. While editing, the live preview showed that the first 3 lines had one less space before the comment than was actually there. This was odd, but I thought I'd just add a space to those lines. In the live preview they now lined up. But when I pressed the button to save the edits, suddenly they had 1 extra space in the actual display of the assembly code and they no longer aligned.

So I edited it again and removed the extra space. Sure enough the code in the editor looked fine, but the preview showed 1 too few spaces on those lines. But when I saved it, they came back and everything aligned.

Answer (score 7):

They are caused by tabs, and yes, tabs are "evil" on Stack Exchange. [**They break code formatting**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146114/auto-expand-tab-character-in-code-formatting).

Here is shown on the real post, no problem!

> [image: real post: correctly aligned]

This is shown in the editor, still looks good!

> [image: editor: correctly aligned]

And this is shown in the preview... hmm?

> [image: preview: comments on line 3-5 are missing a whitespace]

Finally, this is shown on [the revision's source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/18d7f9f7-844b-49d5-9f8b-dc7104499d93/view-source)... eh?

> [image: revision source: too many tabs on line 1&7]

The fix is easy but cumbersome: **don't use tabs, align (manually) with spaces instead**.

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes some sense. I couldn't figure out what was wrong and basically just modified what was already there. Seems odd that in pre-formatted text with monospaced fonts that tabs would be an issue, but I guess that's where we are. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: "align (manually) with spaces instead" please don't do that by hand but use an editor converting tabs to spaces instead :-)